# Spring Webflux - logging connection ID and new Connection log not displayed when using Webflux webclient

Tags: java, logging, spring-webflux

Many tutorials online are pointing out the importance of having connection ID in a Spring Webflux application.

For instance, see this screenshot taken from a presentation in a conference.

[image: connection ID]

However, I am not getting those IDs. I can only see the part with the time, up until the [ctor-http-nio5].

I cannot see the connection ID, I cannot see the statement "New http connection"

What can be the root cause of me not being able to display such? I really would like to see those interesting logs.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This ID is unique for each of the connections made to your server and you can extract it by calling the getLogPrefix() method of ServerWebExchange class and can append it to your logs by directly or by putting it to the MDC.

By default spring framework logs this id in the framework logs.
These framework logs are at the DEBUG level so you need to enable debug level to see the logs with ids.
By adding the following configuration to the application.properties you can see the logs with ids.

logging.level.org.springframework=DEBUG

Comment: Indeed. Many thanks @Tharuka
Just asking, is it possible to have the same, but not at debug level? 
I know I can just enable debug for this class only, but I was wondering if there is a way to have those at info

Comment: I'm not sure whether it is possible to have the same at the info level since those logs are at the debug level.